# Spring Kafka: How to start a stopped MessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, spring, spring-kafka

I use Spring Kafka. I want to stop receiving messages if an error occurred during processing, and then resume receiving after a while.
I saw that spring kafka has a `CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler` handler.
But as far as I understand, it only stops reading. Is it possible to start reading back using standard means?

```
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String,String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory(){
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String,String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.RECORD);
        factory.setConcurrency(2);
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(new CommonContainerStoppingErrorHandler());
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

I've written a handler now, but it doesn't seem like a good solution to me.

```
    @Bean
    CommonErrorHandler eh() {
        return new DefaultErrorHandler((rec, ex) -> {
            System.out.println("Close");
        }, new FixedBackOff(1000L, 1)) {

            @Override
            public void handleRemaining(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records,Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
                if (container!=null && container.isRunning()){
                    container.stop();
                    taskExecuror.schedule(()->container.start(), delay);
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

And another question, as far as I understand, when concurrency is specified 2, child containers are created inside the main container, which are responsible for consumers. The parent container is passed to the method `public void handleRemaining(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records,Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container)`, and calling `stop` for this container stops receiving messages from all partitions. What will happen if a message is currently being processed in one of the containers, will `stop` method wait for the end of the processing? Will the offset be saved after processing?

Answer (score 0):

In your first scenario, why can't you use the error handler with normal retrying facilities if you want to continue processing after a while? You can try retry with an exponential backoff or something similar. As far as I can see, that accomplishes the same result. If you have a strict use case to continue the container after some delay, then programmatically starting the container, as shown above, is a valid strategy.

For the second question, when stopping the container, it waits for all the fetched records to process completely before stopping the container. If you enable the `stopImmediate` property on the container, then the container stops after processing the current record.